# Consuming rest web service continuously from spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I consume an external rest endpoint from my spring boot application continuously? This end point returns new messages when invoked.

Comment: Hi sanjeet, I would suggest a @Schedule for this matter. And a FailSafe library (https://github.com/jhalterman/failsafe) for this as you keep consuming the endpoint. This could also be a simple jar file, in the crontab scheduled in linux only to run each x seconds.

Comment: A good starting point: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: @Brother : Thanks for your response ,but I was looking for something similar to message listener from jms i.e rest endpoint listenere.  Please suggest.

Comment: Hi @sanjeet, this involves concepts like publish/subscribe in the case of message listener. For the rest enpoint, unless you can subscribe to it, you need some kind of pooling mechanism. The only way I see is: you have your spring-boot service running checking for a topic/queue message that when you receive, you check the web service .. and you have another service publishing the message there for you each interval.

Comment: hi @Brother Can I use while loop to consume the rest end point with PostConstruct annotation. Will that be a correct approach ?

Comment: No @sanjeet, there are so many variables involved in here. First, how often there are new messages? If it is a loop, you will keep calling forever. Better using schedulers for it. Where after x seconds, you call the endpoint, then it releases the resources and threads, then after x seconds, calls again, etc ... But I suggest you study well first about thread, schedule and rest as it seems new to the spring / java framework.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, unless the external endpoint has the ability to register a callback of yours, otherwise, you can't have a rest endpoint listener like JMS.

In another way, usually, we can have a scheduled job to pull from the external endpoint continuously. And there are serval kind of scheduled jobs which explained in details at here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_scheduling.htm

Comment: Can I use while loop to consume the rest end point with @PostConstruct annotation. Will that be a correct approach ?

Comment: yes, you can. But you'd better open another thread to do that. I suggest you put your logic into a method in another service and mark the method with `@Async`.